# Best practice to remove confidential fields from Keycloak event logging?

Tags: keycloak

Some events in Keycloak, e.g. `user_not_found`, `resolve_required_actions` log the username in the process and I seem not to be able to find the source of this.

Also cannot find anything in the official logging documentation in regards to this, but I was wondering what the best practice would be to remove this information from the logs (both in admin console and log output)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up implementing my own event-listener SPI by extending and overwriting the [`JbossLoggingEventListener`](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/events/log/JBossLoggingEventListenerProvider.java) and removing unwanted fields from the event payload.